# How to use a TimeSpan array as an argument for CommandLineParser in c#

Tags: c#, command-line-parser

I am trying to use a TimeSpan[] as an argument for `CommandLineParser` and set Default value(s).

I tried this but get compile error "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, ..."

```
[Option("RefreshTimeOfDay", Default = new TimeSpan[] { TimeSpan.Parse ("09:00:00") }]
public IEnumerable<TimeSpan> RefreshTimeOfDay { get; set; }
```

Comment: I think you'll probably need to accept a string array and then parse it at the beginning of the method.